# How to take R.string value instead of hardcoded value, if it's a class field?

Tags: java, android, xml, string, resources

For instance I want to take this

```
public class SomeClass {
    public static final String GREET_STRING = "Hello!";
    //...
```

and change it to something like:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public static final String GREET_STRING = getString(R.string.greet_string);
    //...
```

Can this be done or do I need some kind of Context instantiation to get the resources for the string loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `getString()` you will need a context. A Resource string cannot be `static final` because it is possible for String resources to change as you change Locales (if you have multiple String files such as `strings.xml (us)` and `strings.xml (uk)`)

Comment: So I have to pass in a context to the class and set the string that way?

Comment: You can set class fields to `R.string.xxxxx` but you have to do so with a context. You could pass the context to the class but it would make more sense to set the field inside your `Activity`

Comment: `SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
sc.field = getString(R.string.xxxxx);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public abstract class SomeClass extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static String GREET_STRING(Context context) {
        if (context == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return context.getResources().getString(R.string.greet_string);
    }
}
```

Res/Value/String:

```
<resources>
    <string name="greet_string">Hello!</string>
</resources>
```

Call SomeClass from MainClass

```
public class MainClass extends SomeClass {
    private final static String TAG = MainClass.class.getName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // call SomeClass from MainClass
        Log.i(TAG, SomeClass.GREET_STRING(this));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways access the string inside the class which is not extending Activity or Fragment.

1. Pass `Context` or `Activity` to class constructor

   ```
   public class SomeClass {
       private Context context;
       public SomeClass(Context context) {
           this.context = context;
       }
       public static final String GREET_STRING = context.getString(R.string.greet_string);
   }
   ```
2. The second way is if you don`t want to pass context to class. You need to create an instance of the Application and static function get instance.

   ```
   public class App extends Application {
           private static App instance = null;
           @Override
           public void onCreate() {
               super.onCreate();
               instance = this;
           }
           public static App getInstance() {
               // Return the instance
               return instance;
           }
   }       

   public class SomeClass {
           public static final String GREET_STRING = App.getInstance().getString(R.string.greet_string);
       }
   ```